# Is it possible to include a CSS file depending on a JS variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, screen-resolution

Following this previous question **[JQuery distinct between smartphones, tablet or computers with different sizes but the same $(window).width()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51650914/jquery-distinct-between-smartphones-tablet-or-computers-with-different-sizes-bu)** I now that I know the real sizes from the devices I use thank to window.screen.width , I would like to use one CSS file or another depending of this size, like for example:

```
<script>
var w = window.screen.width;
if(w < 800){
  //I should include somehow this <link href="{{ asset('assets/css/firstCSS.css') }}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
} else {
  //Adding the second CSS file... <link href="{{ asset('assets/css/secondCSS.css') }}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
}
</script>
```

I know this code looks horrible but I'm not able to get a solution.

(Edited)It is possible to use a css file depending on a value from JavaScript? Don't answer me yes... and show me how please.

Comment: Are you looking for media queries?  https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp. If you want to make your site responsive to every device, try using media queries.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16502401/javascript-variable-to-css) link. It might help.

Comment: Mediaquerys works like the $(window).width() values... I need this media queries but using the values from window.screen.width

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes of course you can do it:

- Create a new `link` element.
- Give it a `href` based on your variable.
- Append this `link` to the `head` of the document.

This is how should be your code.

```
var w = window.screen.width;
var link = document.createElement("link");
link.type = "text/css";
link.rel = "stylesheet";
if (w < 800) {
  link.href = "{{ asset('assets/css/firstCSS.css') }}";
} else {
  link.href = "{{ asset('assets/css/secondCSS.css') }}";
}
document.head.appendChild(link);
```